# Рандомный вывод текста

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется код:

```
<div id="show1" style="display: none;">Текст1<div>
<div id="show2" style="display: none;">Текст2<div>
<div id="show3" style="display: none;">Текст3<div>
<div id="show4" style="display: none;">Текст4<div>
<div id="show5" style="display: none;">Текст5<div>

<script>
var a;

function getRandom() {
    return Math.random();
}

a = getRandom();
a = a * 5;

if (0 < a < 1) {
    d = document.getElementById('show1').style.display = "";
}
if (1 < a < 2) {
    d = document.getElementById('show2').style.display = "";
}
if (2 < a < 3) {
    d = document.getElementById('show3').style.display = "";
}
if (3 < a < 4) {
    d = document.getElementById('show4').style.display = "";
}
if (4 < a < 5) {
    d = document.getElementById('show5').style.display = "";
}
</script>
```

вопрос: в чем ошибка?

Comment: Нашел сам)

Comment: Math.random() возвращает число от 0 до 1ицы, естественно не работает, всегда будет выполнятся первый if..<br>
И в вашем случае надо не тупо набор ифов делать а использовать цепочку, тобишь if(....)else if(....)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно возвращать рандом в Вашем случае только в диапазоне от 1 до 5

Comment: зачем клонировать стандартную функцию рандома если она делает тоже ???